# jwplayer setup as object (without javascript) but with playlist

Tags: html, video, jwplayer, playlist

I want to setup jwplayer with playlist and without javascript. I use "object" embed option to add player to the page (without javascript).  Is it possible to "inject" playlist to jwplayer without "JW Embedder" javascript and without additional request to the server for rss playlist file? Maybe some `flashVars`? or special `<div>` or other tag at `html` with list of tracks?